# ¿Cómo validar una session más campo name de los formularios?

Tags: php, session

El siguiente código evita que se pierda los datos llenados en los campos de formulario, mediante una sesión llamada `datos_form` a pesar de refrescar la página o de cerrar la pestaña y volver abrirla en otra los datos no se pierden.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $_SESSION['datos_form']['name']; ?>">
```

Pero existe un problema que esto `<?= $_SESSION['datos_form']['name']; ?>` solo funciona al llenar los campos vacíos, es decir si existe una sesión guardada con los datos del `input` + `name`

Entonces como puedo validar una sesión + el valor del campo de la etiqueta `name` de los formularios, para evitar que al ejecutar el archivo PHP me muestre un error por cada campo.

> Notice: Undefined index: datos_form in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\datos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar. Utiliza el operador ternario ( test?valor1:valor2 ), en su versión corta que devuelve el valor de test como valor1 si éste no está presente.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= isset($_SESSION['datos_form']['name'])?$_SESSION['datos_form']['name']:""; ?>">
```

*Edit: he cambiado el uso del operador, sustituyendo el test por un `isset` que verifique si efectivamente existe o no la variable, y reemplazando pues el primer valor por lo que realmente necesitamos.*

---

*Nota: Hay otra opción. Entiendo que si tienes ya la sesión activa es porque hay un código PHP previo a esta etapa. Podrías prerellenar el array `$_SESSION['datos_form']`con cadenas vacías (`""`) en caso de que no haya datos. De este modo, podrías ahorrarte completamente el test en linea, que queda incómodo y feo, lo cual a la larga produce bugs difíciles de encontrar.*

---

Edición sacada de la evolución del código en los comentarios:

```
<?php
$fields = ["nombre", "apellido"]; // Aquí se añaden todos los campos necesarios
foreach($fields as $field) {
  $formdata[$field] = isset($_SESSION['datos_form'][$field])?$_SESSION['datos_form'][$field]:"";
}
$_SESSION['datos_form'] = $form_data;
?>

<html>
....
...
....
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?=$form_data['nombre']?>" />
...
....
...
</html>
```

Comment: Podrías, por ejemplo, crear un array con todos los nombres de los campos (`$fields = ["nombre", "apellido", ...];`). Luego, con un `foreach($fields as $field)` verificas cada campo (`$formdata = isset($_POST[$field])? $_POST[$field]:"";`). Luego, un simple `$_SESSION["datos_form"] = $formdata;` y los puedes usar directamente.

Comment: No, no. La asignación de `$formdata` a `$_SESSION["datos_form"]` se hace antes de entrar en el html. Luego, en cada campo, dejas el código como lo tenías originalmente (`<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $_SESSION['datos_form']['name']; ?>">`) por ejemplo. Aunque, sinceramente, no estoy seguro de por qué usas SESSION en este código, así que podrías dejar de lado esa asignación y usar directamente `value="<?= $formdata['name']; ?>"`.

Comment: Me doy cuenta de que en mi comentario anterior me he dejado algo fundamental. La linea correcta sería:  `$formdata[$field] = isset($_POST[$field])? $_POST[$field]:"";`. Siento las molestias.

Comment: Este último cambio hace lo que habías pedido inicialmente, en la pregunta original. No se menciona cómo cargar los datos desde `$_POST`, pero si quieres tenerlos en cuenta en la asignación a `$formdata` lo puedes hacer fácilmente.

Comment: El dato del formulario se mantiene, no se borran pero se pierde el resto de validaciones como esta comprobación `if(isset($_SESSION['datos_form']['radio']) && $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] == $key ) {}` pero bueno creo que va a tocar hacerlo desde el `array` = `$_SESSION['datos_form']` eso ya lo tengo y funciona bien, pero quería ver si existía otra forma más optimizable, porque me tocaría repetir 40 veces esto `$name = isset($datosForm['name']) ? $datosForm['name']: '';`  por cada campo de los formularios.

Comment: Observe la validación con [array](https://ideone.com/mN1AIt) no creo que se pueda hacer más simple, creo que me estoy complicando la vida, pero siempre es bueno saber otras opciones...

Answer (score 1):

No puedes acceder a un index de un array sin asegurarte que el array posea esa key, para eso debes ocupar isset()

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= isset($_SESSION['datos_form']['name']) ? $_SESSION['datos_form']['name'] :""; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, el problema es porque una variable de sesión es valida siempre y cuando esta exista, y es obvio que dicha variable no existe antes de que se envíe o se ejecute la orden de crear la variable de sesión con lo almacenado.

Por lo que debes hacer una validación, para hacerlo sin perjudicar tanto la lectura de tu código usa operadores ternarios:

Para saber si existe el valor de $_SESSION['DATOS']['NAME']

```
$valor = (isset($_SESSION["DATOS"]["NAME"]) && !empty($_SESSION["DATOS"]["NAME"])) ? $_SESSION["DATOS"]["NAME"] : ""; 

echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$valor.'">';
```

Es una forma sencilla, o puedes simplemente poner todo en la misma línea, lo que hace ahí en esencia es decir "si existe la variable de sesión datos índice nombre y no está vacía entonces el valor de $valor es igual al de la variable de sesión de lo contrario es igual a un string vacío.